# Locating autopsy results for suicide in NYC in 1931?

Tags: death-records, new-york-city, 1930s, cause-of-death

Has anyone had any success in obtaining a police file or coroner's report from the 1930's?

I am having difficulty finding out if those records were destroyed or not. If not, I cannot find any place that has them.

Comment: New York has adopted the 100 year rule, over the objections of genealogists. Therefore you may be denied access to the records until 2031. New York does not necessarily have the records. You mention 1931 and you may receive a form letter with a blocked checked you are not granted access to those records under New York Law Sec XXXXXX.